# Error when connecting to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I cannot understand what is going on I am so confused it says UNKNOWN DATABASE on the exception error. When I do change the database name to "dbmdgoserver" only, it connects. I mean both databases exist within my PHPMyAdmin i can't see why it cannot connect.

```
con.ConnectionString = String.Format("server=localhost;user=root;database=dbmdgoserver2")
    Try
        con.Open()
        MsgBox("SUCCESS")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please (remove the 'String.Format()' part):

con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=dbmdgoserver2"

Comment: Also, try this: con.ConnectionString ="server=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbmdgoserver2;Integrated Security=True;"

Comment: I dont understand tho i tried running the whole application without WAMP and it still says connected

Comment: oohhh i see there was something running on the background named mysqld.exe i ended the task and poof it realized that there is no WAMP Server running